# SKView.presentScene(scene) doesn't work but SKView.presentScene(scene, transition) do work

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift5

I'm building a game. With a main ViewController and sub controller for each scene: the start screen and the game level

At startup I present the StartScreen. Then When the play button is pressed I present the Game scene (and add his controller)

Once the game is over I present the Start screen.

Problem : the start screen doesn't appear and the game level stays in place.

The code is actually called and the SKView.scene hold a reference to the right one (start screen). but nothing change visually.

```
public func gameEnded() {
    print("game ended", skView.scene)
    gameSceneController.willMove(toParent: nil)
    gameSceneController.removeFromParent()
    skView.presentScene(startScene)
    print(skView.scene)
}
```

However, if I add a transition parameter to the presentScene method everything works as intended... The start screen replace the game scene.

```
public func gameEnded() {
    print("game ended", skView.scene)
    gameSceneController.willMove(toParent: nil)
    gameSceneController.removeFromParent()
    skView.presentScene(startScene, transition: .crossFade(withDuration: 0.2)) //the ONLY difference in the whole code base
    print(skView.scene)
}
```

Any idea what could be the reason?

Nota : I'm currently using Xcode 11 beta 7

Comment: According to your above description, presentScene(_:transition:) can initialize a scene, while presentScene(_) only works when there is an old scene which should be replaced.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, I'm not sure what you mean. Both scenes are initialised at start up and a reference is kept in the main SKViewController and I use those reference to call the "presentScene" methods. Also in both case the print(skView.scene) print the name of the startScreenScene but it's not on the screen.

Comment: Actually the code here is not as expected. You may have to divide the logics into two or three functions to test the intentions.

Comment: What do you mean by "the code here is not as expected"?
Regarding the division there is literally 3 instructions in this method, if I divid it into 3 methods I don't see what will be the gain here.

Comment: If you want to debug this issue, you may have to test each line of code separately.

Comment: E.Coms advice is incorrect.  First, you are most likely not using view controllers in the proper way. Second, you are probably attaching to the wrong views.   I am not sure why you have multiple controllers, so you are going to have to expand your code a little more so people can get an understanding of what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks @Knight0fDragon, The idea here is to separate the logic of every part. The same way the UIView logic is separated. Note the SKScene don't have a SKS file also I tried without the controller and I have the same problem. If you have any advice on the controller architecture for SKScene, there are welcomed.

Comment: You just need separate classes, not controllers

Comment: Do you mean that for this kind of purpose MVC design is not appropriate, or that the UIVIewController is not the right implementation of it?

Comment: yes, MVC does not apply to sprite kit.  In game development, you should adopt ECS (Entity Component System), which is why they created the gameplay kit framework.  That is a little advanced right now.  How you should be handling this is 1 ViewController (a scene controller) and swap your scenes (Some developers use the scenes to swap to other scenes, but I think it is ugly) No need for multiple controllers.  If this was a game console, think of your controller as your "system" and your scenes as your cartridges. The system remains constant, but it is the cartridges that determine the game.

Comment: Totally agree with that, yet, do you still manage your start screen (with all the option/shop/...) with Entities? Or do you put your game logic inside your game scene? (we are slowly drifting away from the main topic :) )

Comment: Shop, option, etc are separate scenes (if you used SKS files it would be easier). Your scenes would have independent logic.  Inside your scenes would be nodes that are entities that run components.  In your case, you would create an OptionScene class, GameScene class, MenuScene class, etc; and you would use your 1 VC to swap between them.